# Java beginner: Is this best practise (randoms and conditionals)?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, random

I've just started learning Java and I've been playing around with a few ideas.  I've written the following small piece of code which when run outputs a different room in a house.  The room is decided by a random integer between the value of 1 and 3.  The code seems to work just fine.  However, as I am new to programming my concern is that I may have misunderstood one of the tutorials informing my work and used an inefficient way to complete it.

Can anyone tell me if am I using the best practises to achieve my desired result and explain any changes I could make to make the code better?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Rooms {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Random random = new Random();
  int roomNumber = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
  String getRoom = "";

  if (roomNumber == 1) {
    getRoom = "Living Room";
  } else if (roomNumber == 2) {
    getRoom = "Kitchen";
  } else if (roomNumber == 3) {
    getRoom = "Bathroom";
  }

  System.out.println(getRoom);

  }
}
```

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, I'd suggest, as a point of style, naming variables according to what they actually represent. So, instead of 'getRoom', I'd use 'roomName', especially since 'getRoom' is the form of an accessor method - someone reading this code for the first time might, on a quick reading, see that as getRoom()

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply put the `rooms` into an array:

```
String[] rooms = { "Living Room", "Kitchen", "Bathroom" };
int roomNumber = random.nextInt(rooms.length);
System.out.println(rooms[roomNumber]);
```

**Background:** [Random.nextInt(n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) takes an `int` argument as the upperbound which returns an integer between `0` and (but not including) *n*. Using `rooms.length` here will allow you to select a random index from the array without causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Would be better if you used `rooms.length` in your call to `random.nextInt`.

Comment: Can you explain why it would be better to use `rooms.length`?

Comment: @user1914525 Using `rooms.length` allows you to add or remove from the array without any changes to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. The only thing I can recommend is: Using switch instead of multiple-if's with else's is faster, but as you run this random once, that doesn't really matter. That switch if you need:

```
switch (roomNumber) {
    case 1:  getRoom = "Living Room";
             break;
    case 2:  getRoom = "Kitchen";
             break;
    case 3:  getRoom = "Bathroom";
             break;   
    default: getRoom = "Error!";
             break;
}
```

Also you can use List or Arrays. Arrays will speed you up too, always use arrays if you have defined number of elements.

```
String[] rooms = new String[]{"Living Room", "Kitchen", "Bathroom"};
getRoom = rooms[random.nextInt(rooms.length)];
```